# ViewController created with storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "") not able to access sending ViewController's properties/functions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, null, option-type

I know the implicitly unwrapping optional value question has been answered a million times, but this is so weird.  I used storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SettingsViewController") to create the current view controller, but I can't access the properties of the sending view controller.  Im getting the error from the optional value of an isHidden property of an object in the sending view controller being nil.  I checked to make sure that all the required outlets are properly linked, and they are as far as I can tell. No idea what's going on.  Here's the code where isHidden is nil:

```
@IBAction func hideSearchRadiusPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    if hideSearchRadiusButton.titleLabel?.text == "Hide Search Radius" {
       
        mapViewController.searchRadiusView.isHidden = true
        mapViewController.searchRadiusView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        hideSearchRadiusButton.titleLabel?.text = "Show Search Radius"
        
    } else if hideSearchRadiusButton.titleLabel?.text == "Show Search Radius" {
        
        mapViewController.searchRadiusView.isHidden = false
        mapViewController.searchRadiusView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        hideSearchRadiusButton.titleLabel?.text = "Hide Search Radius"
        
    }
    
}
```

Here is the code in which the current view controller (SettingsViewController), is instantiated.  this is done within MapViewController, the initial view controller:

```
  @IBAction func settingsButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    // Identifier is under 'Storyboard ID' in the identity inspector for SettingsViewController
    guard let settingsViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SettingsViewController") else {return}
    settingsViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    settingsViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
    present(settingsViewController, animated: true)
    
}
```

I get the error on the 'mapViewController.searchRadiusView.isHidden = true' line, but I'm sure Id get it for the isUserInteractionEnabled part as well.  Any idea why this error would occur on an isHidden property? Again the outlet for the searchRadiusView (which is in another view controller, that's why I call it as a part of mapViewController) is properly linked.  thanks for any help.

Comment: Simple, you called it when your view has not been created yet, for sample create it with `let vc = SomeViewController()` , views only get created after `viewDidLoad` even if it marked with `!`

Comment: Can you find out what's nil first, using the debugger? It's either `mapController` or `searchRadiusView`.

Comment: Try to add a breakpoint there and print the `mapController ` or `searchRadiusView ` out, it probably be nil

Comment: it is the searchRadiusView that is nil

Comment: So how do I make it not nil? When I looked up other solutions for this, the problem was usually an improperly linked outlet, but mine is fine

Comment: you will have to unwrap it with a guard let or an if let before using the property.

Comment: How will that make it not be nil? Or maybe you misunderstood my question.  Im saying why is this value nil in the first place and how can I change that.  With an if or guard let, that's just going to avoid the fatal error, but it won't solve the issue that the value is nil

Comment: Show more code. How is mapViewController declared/initialized? How is it related to the controller containing the code above?

Comment: UIViewController does not have isHidden property

Comment: @Don mapViewController is the initial view controller and the controller which Im referencing it from is a view controller instantiated upon pressing a button in mapViewController.  Ill show the instantiation code in an edit.  cora the isHidden property is applied to a UIView, not a view controller.

Comment: Has the view controller been presented?  If not then the view hierarchy won't have been loaded.  You can call `mapViewController.loadViewIfNeeded()` to force the load

Comment: Still not clear how mapViewController is declared/initialized within settingsViewController. Looks like you need to reference the transitioningDelegate instead.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.
Try putting ? in         mapViewController?.searchRadiusView?.isHidden = true
What you can do is create 3 vars in mapViewController.
`customIsHidden, customUserInt, title`.
Assign value in hideSearchRadiusPressed func.
in mapViewController's viewDidLoad.
`mapViewController.searchRadiusView.isHidden = customIsHidden`
`mapViewController.searchRadiusView.isUserInteractionEnabled = customUserInt`
`hideSearchRadiusButton.titleLabel?.text = title`

Comment: Have you check isViewLoaded() ? If the UI for the mapViewController.searchRadiusView not loaded yet, every time you try to access to its subview properties you will get this error.

Comment: @derek Easiest way to force viewController create view is with `let _ = settingsViewController.view` right below where you create it.

Comment: Paulw11, mapViewController is the initial vc, so that has been presented, and SettingsViewController is presented before this function can be called. I tried that method in the viewDidLoad and it caused a whole other host of issues with the delegates in my actual MapViewController, so I got rid of it.  Don, I initialize it with 'let mapViewController = MapViewController()'.  I am not familiar with transitioning delegates.  If I use that, how can I still access the vc's properties?  Yigit, when I call that on mapViewController, it gives me false! But trying Paul's idea causes other fatal errors

Comment: So to sum up, it says mapViewController.isViewLoaded = false,  but when I put mapViewController.loadViewIfNeeded() in viewDidLoad, I get nil for my mapView delegate in my MapViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved my own problem.  I'm going to make this more general in case anyone else runs into this issue.  If you are instantiating what I will call a 'newViewController' programmatically, like I was, you will need to add a transitioning delegate:

```
class SendingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func sendingButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        // Identifier argument of 'instantiateViewController' is under 'Storyboard ID' in the identity inspector for NewViewController
        guard let newViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "NewViewController") else {return}

        // Presentation style up to you. I did it this way because I am using a custom transition
        newViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

        // Set the newViewController's transitioningDelegate property to self (the sending view controller)
        newViewController.transitioningDelegate = self

        present(newViewController, animated: true)
    
    }

}
```

In NewViewController, when you want to access the properties of the SendingViewController, all you have to do is reference the transitioning delegate:

```
class NewViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
        // Remember, we set the current view controller's transitioningDelegate as SendingViewController before, when we were INSIDE SendingViewController, by using newViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
        if let sendingVC = self.transitioningDelegate as? SendingViewController {
            
                // Now we can access properties of the sendingVC.  
                // In my case, I needed to access a UIView, put your code below in place of mine
                sendingVC.customView.isHidden = true
                sendingVC.customView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            }

    }

}
```

Hopefully this helps someone.